# Error: Invalid HTML for md-menu: Expected the menu to contain a `md-menu-content` element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying angular material menu

```
 <md-menu class="address-menu" layout="row " layout-align="end-center " flex="10 ">
       <md-button  ng-click="vm.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event);vm.showAddressMenu(cartItemDetails)" class="address-menu-icon">
           <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
       </md-button>
      <apt-address-menu ng-if="itemDetails.showAddressMenu " details="itemDetails "></apt-address-menu>
</md-menu>
```

here I am trying to make a directive for md-menu-content like below:

```
<md-menu-content width="4">
<md-menu-item >
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.DUPLICATE"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item ng-click="vm.showShippingLocations()">
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.CHANGE_ADDRESS"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item ng-click="vm.changeDefaultAddress()">
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.DEFAULT_ADDRESS"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item >
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.DELETE_CART"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

But while doing so,
I am getting the error:

```
Error: Invalid HTML for md-menu: Expected the menu to contain a `md-menu-content` element.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your html code that begins with <md-menu-content is that the teplate you have for another directive called aptAddressMenu ?

Comment: @Tik
Yes,Its is the directive template

Comment: i dont have a solution for you sorry. i doubt it would work. any reason you cant keep it nested as it is?

Comment: because the menu is resuable here

Answer (score 0):

The md-menu directive will require some elements in the DOM when it compiles, at least in 1.1.4.
Specifically it needs a *md-menu-content* right under the *md-menu* element.

This is why *md-menu-content* cannot be put in a template of a directive of your own, because the DOM will look like this:

```
<md-menu>
<my-directive> <- Not md-menu-content
***here starts your directive***
<md-menu-content>
***code of your directive***
</md-menu-content>
***here ends your directive***
</my-directive>
<md-menu>
```

Fortunately it does not need the *md-menu-item* to be right under the *md-menu-content*, so what you could do is wrap only the *md-menu-item* inside your directive.

This should work:

**AptAddressMenu directive template**

```
<md-menu-item >
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.DUPLICATE"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item ng-click="vm.showShippingLocations()">
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.CHANGE_ADDRESS"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item ng-click="vm.changeDefaultAddress()">
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.DEFAULT_ADDRESS"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item >
    <md-button translate="ADDRESS_MENU.DELETE_CART"></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

**Parent**

```
<md-menu class="address-menu" layout="row " layout-align="end-center " flex="10 ">
       <md-button  ng-click="vm.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event);vm.showAddressMenu(cartItemDetails)" class="address-menu-icon">
           <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
       </md-button>
<md-menu-content>
      <apt-address-menu ng-if="itemDetails.showAddressMenu " details="itemDetails "></apt-address-menu>
</md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```